# maximize windows forms with label size

Tags: c#, winforms, label, maximize

I made a custom MessageBox and have a problem with maximize the msgBox with the label size. If my label is too long and too big, so i want my custom MessageBox grow bigger or smaller too depends on label size. Can i set it in Windows forms option or what can i do?

my code:

```
      public static DialogResult Show(string Text, string Caption, string btnOk, string btnCancel)
      {

        MsgBox = new CustomMsgBox();
        MsgBox.label1.Text = Text;
        MsgBox.button1.Text = btnOk;
        MsgBox.button2.Text = btnCancel;
        MsgBox.AutoSize = true;
        result = DialogResult.No;
        MsgBox.ShowDialog();

        return result;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        result = DialogResult.Yes;
        MsgBox.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You will need to write a bunch of code to make the dialog grow *proportionally*.  In other words, grow both in the width and the height.  There's nothing in Winforms that makes that easy, you'll have to slug it out yourself.  Not complicated, just annoying code to write.  TextRenderer.MeasureText() required.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do in the `MsgBox_load(object sender, EventArgs e)` is add this code:

```
private void MsgBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Width = label1.Width + label1.Location.X;
    //do other things you need in the load event.
}
```

This will set the set the `width` of the MsgBox according to the Width + the X-coordinate location of the label1`.    As the label may or may not be on the complete left side, this would show the complete label and maximize the MsgBox accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much, but can i use the same way to recognize the height of the label and then change the msgbox too?

Comment: definitly should be possible yes.

Comment: i tried copy paste your code but the result is still the same. Where should I put it in my code? under those codes what i wrote above?

Comment: In the `MsgBox.cs` then add the load event and place the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

**In designer**

1. Drag and drop a `FlowLayoutPanel` control, resize the flowlayout width as you need
2. Drag and drop your `Label` control

**In .cs file**

For example i'm binding some text in form load event and calling the resize event

```
    private void CustMsgBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Binding some long text to the label
        label1.Text = "ga,dsa,bdas,bcc,asbcc,asc,asbc,a c,asc,n asc,baskcas,c sam ckavcmas cmas ckasvmas cmas ckavcma cmaga,dsa,bdas,bcc,asbcc,asc,asbc,a c,asc,n asc,baskcas,c sam ckavcmas cmas ckasvmas cmas ckavcma cmaga,dsa,bdas,bcc,asbcc,asc,asbc,a c,asc,n asc,baskcas,c sam ckavcmas cmas ckasvmas cmas ckavcma cmaga,dsa,bdas,bcc,asbcc,asc,asbc,a c,asc,n asc,baskcas,c sam ckavcmas cmas ckasvmas cmas ckavcma cma";
        this.ResizeWindow(); // Calling this event will resize the label and window
    }
```

After binding some text to the label, call the below method

```
    private void ResizeWindow()
    {
        int iHeight = flowLayoutPanel1.Height;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Height = label1.Height;
        this.Height += (flowLayoutPanel1.Height - iHeight); //This will increase the height of the window accordingly
        this.Top=Convert.ToInt32((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height-this.Height)/2); //This will position the window center vertically
    }
```

Comment: Just replace `Width` in place of `Height`.Please mark as answer, if it help you. So it may help others.